# SSH on Ventura - How to deal with hosts running very old versions of OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, ventura

Ventura [13.0 Beta (22A5352e)] ships with OpenSSH_9.0p1.

According to the OpenSSH release notes:

> This release disables RSA signatures using the SHA-1 hash algorithm  by default. This change has been made as the SHA-1 hash algorithm is  cryptographically broken, and it is possible to create chosen-prefix  hash collisions for <USD$50K

The web host to which I want to connect has OpenSSH_5.3p1 which seems to be configured to only offer RSA and DSA:

```
no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

I would prefer to use ed25519 keys. I temporarily "fixed" the problem by adding the following to my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

There must be a better way. Of course, I can't make the web host upgrade their OpenSSH, so the fix will have to be on my end.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is your configuration not a "fix"?  You can't force the other end to offer key exchange it doesn't support.  I think I would localize that change to specific hosts, though, in `$HOME/.ssh/config`. rather than making it global.

Comment: Compile a terribly old version of OpenSSH (5.3 is from 2009) and use that special version only when interacting with the special host. This will be not very good for security, unless maybe you backport various security fixes...

Comment: Localizing the change for the specific host using the config file worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the server won't take ed25519 keys, you can't use ed25519 keys. You have to use a key type that the server supports, end of story.

As long as the OpenSSH client still supports some feature in common with the server, you can keep using it. If it's disabled by default, you can enable it for a specific server by adding a `Host` section to the file `~/.ssh/config` in your home directory. Something like:

```
Host my-old-server.example.com
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

If you're not sure what settings to change, here's how you can find out:

- You can list supported settings with `ssh -Q sig`, etc. Use shell completion or see `man ssh_config` for what you can put after `-Q`.
- You can see the default allowed settings by running `ssh -G localhost`. This dumps the configuration that `ssh` uses when connecting to localhost.
- You can see what settings your client offers and what settings the client supports by connecting with logging on: `ssh -vvv my-old-server.example.com`.

Note that for ordinary SSH usage, even signatures based on SHA-1 are fine. SHA-1 is broken when it comes to [collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack), and this is catastrophic for public-key infrastructures: an attacker who wants to impersonate `goodserver.example.com` can calculate a ”garbage“ name such that a certificate request for `goodserver.example.com` and the garbage name have the same SHA-1 hash, register the garbage name and obtain a valid certificate for it, and because of the SHA-1 hash collision that certificate is also valid for `goodserver.example.com`. This is how TLS (including HTTPS) is typically used, but not SSH. When you connect directly to a server, the security property that matters for the [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is second preimage resistance (so the attacker can't impersonate the server directly), and SHA-1 is still unbroken in this respect.

As for RSA, it's just as secure as ECDSA or Ed25519, its only downside is that it's a bit slower.